# Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'object'. 'Select' not found

Tags: c#, linq, object

I was trying to use same linq object multiple times but it throws the above error.Here is my code.The error is on

```
var GridData = (from x in GridValue select new { x.EmployeeID, x.LastName, x.FirstName, x.HireDate, x.HomePhone });
```

this line

---

```
public static  object GetData() {
    PopulateGridDataContext populateGridContext = new PopulateGridDataContext();
    var data = from x in populateGridContext.Employees select x;
    return data;
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //PopulateGridDataContext pgdc = new PopulateGridDataContext();
    var GridValue = WorkingWithLinq.GetData();
    //var data = from x in pgdc.Employees select x;
    var GridData = (from x in GridValue select new { x.EmployeeID, x.LastName, x.FirstName, x.HireDate, x.HomePhone });
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: The error is on var GridData = (from x in GridValue select new { x.EmployeeID, x.LastName, x.FirstName, x.HireDate, x.HomePhone }); this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GetData method returns `object`, which doesn't contain the linq 
 extension methods.  Try returning or casting to `IEnumerable<Employee>`.

i guessed that your items were Employees.  You should be able to hover over the `data` variable to see what the type is.  Use that type as the return value.

Comment: Thanks @BillTarbell .. I got the result by casting the data as iqueryable<Employee> as u suggested .. By adding this line  var GridValue = WorkingWithLinq.GetData() as IQueryable<Employee>;

Comment: Great. I'm glad that helped you out.  If you consider this the answer to your problem then please mark it as the answer so others will know and to give the recognition points.